# How to apply SendKeys Keys.Enter (or Keys.Return) using Selenium in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm putting together a vocabulary list and put together a macro to pull info from vocabulary.com. The search doesn't have a button so I have to use the enter key, but `Keys.Enter` is not working.

The macro still works because you don't necessarily have to press the enter key for the site to show the definition page for the top most autocomplete result that pops up as you type in the search field.

The problem is that not in every case is the top most suggested result the word I am looking for. I need to get that Enter keystroke to work for this macro to be 100% useful.

```
Sub VocabularyWebScraper()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim Keys As Selenium.Keys
Dim count As Long

Sheets("Vocabulary.com Scraping").Activate

Set Driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
Set Keys = CreateObject("Selenium.Keys")
count = 1

While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)
    
    Driver.Get "https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/"
    Driver.FindElementById("search").SendKeys Range("A" & count) + Keys.Enter
  
    Driver.Wait 1000
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B" & count) = Driver.FindElementByClass("short").Text
    Range("C" & count) = Driver.FindElementByClass("long").Text
    
    count = count + 1

Wend

Driver.Quit

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Also, I don't see how manually pressing enter makes any difference to the search results once you have started typing.

Comment: I get it on Driver.FindElementById("search").SendKeys Range("A" & count) + Keys.Return. It doesn't like the Keys.Return. It matters because sometimes the first word that pops up in in the autocomplete is not the word I'm looking. It might be a longer word with the same root as the word I'm searching for. In that case the correct page doesn't show up unless you hit enter, then it returns the page with the exact spelling in the search box.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to make it click on the correct word from the autocomplete list. Not really sure how to do it though. Like maybe a find element from element kind of thing.

Comment: I fixed the Object error I was getting. I forgot to create the Keys object, but the Keys.Return still doesn't want to work. I tried other keys like Keys.ArrowLeft and they work fine, just not Enter or Return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the enter key to work, but just in case anyone else wants to pull definitions from Vocabularly.com here is what worked. I ended up just clicking the button of the specific word I was looking for. Worked perfectly.

```
Sub VocabularyWebScraper()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim count As Long
Dim word As String

Sheets("Vocab Web Scraping").Activate

Set Driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
count = 1

While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)
    
    word = Range("A" & count)

    Driver.Get "https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/"
    Driver.FindElementById("search").SendKeys word
    Driver.Wait 1000
    Driver.FindElementByCss("li[word='" + word + "']").Click
    Driver.Wait 2000
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B" & count) = Driver.FindElementByClass("short").Text
    Range("C" & count) = Driver.FindElementByClass("long").Text
    
    count = count + 1

Wend

Driver.Quit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub